# How to find loop invariant?

Tags: verification, loop-invariant, hoare-logic

I was doing exercise about program verification, and I had some difficulties in finding this loop invariant:

```
y = 0;
while (y != x) {
    y = y + 1;
}
```

the
precondition is x>=0 and the postcondition is x=y

In the loop there is just one variable so I couldn't think any possible relation that is preserved throughout the program. One weak invariant so far is (y>= 0 && y<=x). So what is the suitable loop invariant for this program?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: What do you want to prove about this loop? If the statement you want to prove is weak then a weak invariant is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a hint: loop invariants must be expressed in terms of each iteration `i`. That is, it must be something like "*P* is true before the execution of every iteration `i`". The invariant you've come up with is not expressed as a function of `i`. Try modifying it a little bit and I think you'll find a more suitable loop invariant.

If you get stuck, I recommend you check out the book title "Discrete Mathematics with Applications", by Susanna Epp; it has a chapter on loop invariants and the book is very gentle for beginners.